# Immutable.js undefined and false have the same hashCode()

Tags: javascript, hash, immutable.js

I'm using [Immutable.js](http://devdocs.io/immutable/index#fromjs()) `fromJS` to compare two simple JavaScript objects:

```
const a = fromJS({value: false}).hashCode();
const b = fromJS({value: undefined}).hashCode();

console.log(a, b);
```

1. Why do these JavaScript objects have the same hash code?

> 10995925 10995925

2. What's the cleanest way to ensure hash codes are different for `undefined` and `false`?

Comment: Having the same hashcode is not a bug, it just affects performance. Is there any reason you need the hashcode to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported this as a bug: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1547

...which was subsequently referenced by [differentiate falsy values when hashing (#1547)](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/pull/1549) in the same repo.

...looks like the fix hasn't landed yet, but soon.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1547 has now been fixed and closed.